# Validating JSON input Laravel

Tags: json, validation, laravel

I am using laravel , and json input from the client. I would like to know if there is a way to create a form request that does json validation instead of url parameters. I found this class online :

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

abstract class JsonRequest extends FormRequest {

    /**
     * Get the validator instance for the request.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function getValidatorInstance()
    {
        $factory = $this->container->make('Illuminate\Validation\Factory');

        if (method_exists($this, 'validator'))
        {
            return $this->container->call([$this, 'validator'], compact('factory'));
        }
        return $factory->make(
            $this->json()->all(), $this->container->call([$this, 'rules']), $this->messages(), $this->attributes()
        );
    }
}
```

Now , when I make a class that extends this instead of Request, I am able to validate. This is an example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Middleware\AuthTokenMiddleware;
use App\Http\Requests\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

class VotesCreateRequest extends JsonRequest
{


    public function response(array $errors)
    {

        //
        return response()->json(["error_list" => $errors], 200);


    }


    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {return true;


        if(AuthTokenMiddleware::getUser()->can('access-group',Input::get("grp_id"))){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {


        return [

            'sub_items'=>'required|array',
            'sub_items.*.email' =>'required'
        ];
    }
}
```

But I want to know how to validate items inside items of the json file .

For example, i have :
{"sub_items":["something","another thing","yet another","another ","last"]}

How do I validate if all these items in sub sub_items are of type email ?

Comment: I'm confused. Can't you just decode the json and check all of the values with something like filter_var? http://php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php

Comment: i was looking for a laravel way

Comment: check this out. it might help https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-to-validate-array-fields/replies/7506